# Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'css')

Tags: javascript, html, css, undefined

I am trying to change the circle size when entering a value in the input, and trying to change the color. But I am getting the following error:

> Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'css')

Can any of you be helpfull with what i can do?

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
  const inputsize = document.getElementById("size");
  const inputcolor = document.getElementById("color");
  const circle = document.getElementsByClassName("circle");

  let size = 100;
  let color = "#b66465";

  window.onchange = (event) => {
    let myStyles = "height: " + size + "px; width: " + size + "px; background-color: " + color + ";";
    circle.style.css = myStyles;
  };

  inputcolor.onchange = (event) => {
    color = inputcolor.value;
    let myStyles = "height: " + size + "px; width: " + size + "px; background-color: " + color + ";";
    circle.style.css = myStyles;
  };

  inputsize.onkeyup = (event) => {
    size = inputsize.value;
    let myStyles = "height: " + size + "px; width: " + size + "px; background-color: " + color + ";";
    circle.style.css = myStyles;
  };
});
```

Comment: `circle` is not an *element*, so it has no `style` property.

Comment: Also `style` has no `css` property.

Comment: @Tange007 it should be `circle.style.cssText = myStyles`

Comment: @David I voted to re-open this question as the duplicate you marked, which was about confusion over `querySelector`/`querySelectorAll` wasn't directly related to the question here, which is confused over how to set CSS properties of an element.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It's not just about `querySelector/All`; it's about the `getElementsBy*` family of methods. And that's exactly the error the user is getting: "Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'css')" The error would be different if `circle.style` was defined and had no `css` property (indeed, there might not be any error at all; it just wouldn't work). If they have a question about _that_ error, that can be addressed separately.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue in your code is because `Element.style` has no `css` property. It's intended that you set the individual style properties, which generally map to CSS properties, one by one, not as an entire string of CSS.

In addition, `getElementsByClassName()` returns a collection of Element objects, so you can't call `style` on it directly. If you have multiple `.circle` element in the DOM, you would need to loop through them.

Also note that it's better practice to use `addEventListner()` instead of `onclick` or other `onX` properties.

Below is a working example with these issues addressed.

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const inputSize = document.querySelector("#size");
  const inputColor = document.querySelector("#color");
  const circles = document.querySelectorAll(".circle");
  
  const updateCircles = () => {
    circles.forEach(circle => {
      circle.style.width = inputSize.value + 'px';
      circle.style.height = inputSize.value + 'px';
      circle.style.backgroundColor = inputColor.value;
    });
  }

  inputColor.addEventListener('input', updateCircles);
  inputSize.addEventListener('input', updateCircles);
});
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #000;
  margin: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<label>
   Size:
   <input type="number" id="size" value="100" />
</label>
<label>
   Color:
   <input type="color" id="color" value="#000000" />
</label>

<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
```